# Docker container keep restarting - Angular Nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to run the Angular app using Docker. After I execute it, it keeps restarting

Below is my Dockerfile,

```
# Stage 1: Build Angular App
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim AS build

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

# Add the source code to app
COPY ./ /usr/local/app/

# Install all the dependencies
RUN npm install --force

# Generate the build of the application
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server
FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: project/web
    build:
      context: payment-ui/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
    volumes: 
     - /etc/ssl/2023:/etc/nginx/certs
```

My nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _; 
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        root /home/ubuntu/htdocs;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        server_name plern.co;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        #       auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        #        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        }

        ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl_certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/private.key;

}
```

I run it by using this command,

> sudo docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --no-deps --build web

It run successfully. But after I check it with docker ps, it's showing that it is restarting

Please help.

Comment: Did you check the container logs?